# Do published adventures have human names in their campaign books?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures

I don't have access to any published adventure campaign books, and I noticed that in the PHB, the human names always refer to the Faerûn setting for names.

Does this mean that human names are given in the published adventure campaign books?

Comment: There are free official published adventures, have you looked at those? This is literally a read the book to me question as it stands right now.

Comment: Where could I find them?

Comment: Have you tried the official dndbeyond.com website? They’ve got the basic rules as well.

Comment: I can't access that website. Unfortunately, it's blocked. And I'm not going to get another search browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Consult *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything*.

Appendix B of *Xanathar’s Guide to Everything* has lists of human names inspired several real-world languages. If you want an officially published list of human names, this is where to find it.

Comment: Can I say I don't have access to that either? The only thing I do have access to are the online versions of the PHB, DMG, and MM.

Comment: The only official online versions of those books are at DND Beyond, which you said you didn’t have access to.